# parse query returning wrong objects

Tags: xcode, parse-platform, swift2

I'm using a queryWithSubqueries to impose more than one constraints as follow:

```
func getPosts() {

    let getPostsQuery = PFQuery(className: "allPosts")
    let getRightPostsQuery = PFQuery(className: "allPosts")

    getPostsQuery.whereKey("userId", equalTo: userId) //userId is a string var storing a specific userId
    getRightPostsQuery.whereKey("isItRight", equalTo: true)

    let combinedQuery = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([getPostsQuery, getRightPostsQuery])
    combinedQuery.limit = 15
    combinedQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt")

    combinedQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (posts, error) -> Void in

        if let posts = posts {

            self.postId.removeAll(keepCapacity: true) //postId is an array to store the postIds

            for post in posts {

                self.postId.append(post.objectId!!)
            }
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get all the right posts posted by the user as described by his userId. I tested the query using an userId that has not posted anything. The weird thing is that there are objects returning that do not belong to that particular user. I then tried using an userId that has posted something and the "wrong" posts are also retrieved (isItRight == false), any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you doing this and using a combined query?

```
getPostsQuery.whereKey("userId", equalTo: userId) //userId is a string var storing a specific userId
getRightPostsQuery.whereKey("isItRight", equalTo: true)
```

Try doing this instead

```
getPostsQuery.whereKey("userId", equalTo: userId) //userId is a string var storing a specific userId
getPostsQuery.whereKey("isItRight", equalTo: true)
```

As Parse Docs say, "You can give multiple constraints, and objects will only be in the results if they match all of the constraints. In other words, it's like an AND of constraints."

If you want, there is also another way to add constrains to a query

```
// Using NSPredicate
let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"userId == '\(userId)' AND isItRight == 1")
let query = PFQuery(className: "allPosts", predicate: predicate)
```